# File corrupted when using download attribute for a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, download, digital-signature

My company has an internal network to share digital blueprints and documents, but it has problem: hyperlinks cannot download a document by clicking and the IT guys are too lazy to fix it, so I wrote a script to help my working experience.

Then *strange things* happen, some files (I didn't find the clue why some are working while some are not) are corrupted when downloaded by clicking the hyperlinks that I added the `download` attribute for. However, if you right click on that file then select `save link as...`, the downloaded file is ok.

Is there any reason that the result is different between a link with the `download` attribute and right clicking on a link then pressing `save as`?

It's worth noting that the `.pdf` documents have digital signatures (not sure if it's related).

---

pseudo code for my script:

```
//Iterate all <a> element that do not class "dl-added"
if (looks like document link) {
  link.setAttribute("download", "")
  link.classList.add("dl-added)
}
```

---

A file link element looks like this without my script:

`<a href="http://cdn.company-name.com:5000/upload/1234-5678-abcd/name-of-doc%20%A2%BC%D2%E9%78%90.pdf">name</a>`

and like this with my script:

`<a href="http://cdn.company-name.com:5000/upload/1234-5678-abcd/name-of-doc%20%A2%BC%D2%E9%78%90.pdf" download class="dl-added">name</a>`

---

The binary content of good pdf file downloaded with right click and `save as` looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.7..%;sÅx..1 0 obj 
......
startxref..661568..%%EOF..
```

and a "Corrupted" file looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.7..%;sÅx..1 0 obj 
......
uÛ±1LFIáxw4Ñ#Of²..
```

When I checked it with [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/), I found that the first ~140kb content of them are exactly the same, but the rest ~490kb are different, all files I tested have a similar structure (first xxx kb are good but the rest are bad).

Comment: I think your problem is unrelated.

Comment: @KJ  Sorry I didn't get you, is that means something happend in the network side?

Comment: I think I catch up, so the click and right click download is different, and the simple click might trigger some bug caused by stream content of pdf file? Is there anything I  (client side) can do to prevent / bypass this problem? (except right click/save as, yeah it's working but feels tedious to repeat 20 times for every quest and that's why I wrote that script)

Answer (score 0):

May be the URL has some special characters not match URL rule (at least your browser)

You can URL Decode/Encode one of these  tags then re-test again to confirm the problem. https://www.urldecoder.org

In your case, this is your url without encode, put it in your script.
http://cdn.company-name.com:5000/upload/1234-5678-abcd/name-of-doc x.pdf

Hope that can help you!

Comment: It contains numbers, letters, dot, space, `-` and some regular chinese characters, I think it's valid. Something like `7777DOC-P1-22 阿斯蒂芬安赛飞.pdf`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).